# site is taking too much time to load

Tags: magento2.3.2, loading

My site is very slow.While using ced commerce modules it die.Almost it takes 40 sec to load to open home page and other also.Without it it takes near about 12 sec.I am using lazy loading also.As well as cdn is used for to access images. Then why it is tooooooooo slow.Please let me know any solution.

Comment: Please enable cache from backend.

Comment: Please check cache status, cache is enabled or not, if not then please enabled it, and check ced commerce module's collection flow and remove unnecessary loops and code.

Comment: all caches are enabled.

Comment: i suggest to only use Memcached on your server also use varnish on Magento(recommended). redis cache and PHP-fpm is useful too. after all just set gzip and minify CCS and JS and merge them. you can decrease load time from 23S to 3.6S

Comment: Enjoy using ced commerce.